# Wagtail: How to link a model to an Orderable which links to another model

Tags: django, wagtail

Lets say I have multiple models which require an address e.g. boxing clubs & boxing events. I have considered making the address an abstract and adding the panels everywhere I needed them but figured that creating its own table/model would be cleaner than the address fields being added to each model that needs them.

Now, a boxing club has it's own timetable where it can specify on which day it's in session as well as a location should it be in a different club than usual.

So, my attempt at a solution looks something like this.

```py
class BoxingClub(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        InlinePanel('club_timetable', heading='Timetable Information')
    ]
```

```py
class ClubTimetable(Orderable):
   _DAYS_OF_WEEK = (
        (0, "Monday"),
        ...
        (6, "Sunday")
    )

    attached_to = ParentalKey(
        'club.BoxingClub', related_name='club_timetable')

    linked_location = models.ForeignKey(
        'location.Address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='location_address', null=True)

    weekday = models.IntegerField(
        'Day of training session', choices=_DAYS_OF_WEEK)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('weekday'),
        InlinePanel('linked_location', help_text='Sessions location information.')
    ]
```

```py
class Address(models.Model):

    address_line_1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, help_text='First line of address.')
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(
        max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, help_text='Second line of address.')
    map_coord_lat = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        help_text='Comma separated latitude.'
    )
    map_coord_lon = models.CharField(
        max_length=25,
        help_text='Comma separated longitude.'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('address_line_1'),
        FieldPanel('address_line_2'),
        FieldPanel('map_coord_lat'),
        FieldPanel('map_coord_lon'),
    ]
```

This however, gives me the following error:

```py
File "/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py", line 698, in on_model_bound  
self.db_field = manager.rel

AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'rel'
```

And after some reading, it would appear that this error stems from the inability of having an `InlinePanel` that is linked to a model which is using an `InlinePanel` itself?

If so, it means something like this would not be possible.
[image: Visual Aid of what I am trying to do in this question.]

I'm not clear as to whether I'm doing all the above incorrectly (maybe the `ParentalKey`/`ForeignKey` relationships) or that it cannot work the way I'm trying and the only other alternative I can think of is adding the address panels into any model that needs it but the repetition doesn't make sense to me so I would like to know what the possible solutions could be? Perhaps using it as an abstract was/is a correct workaround?

---

**Edit** - the workaround

> It is not possible to use an `InlinePanel` which contains an `InlinePanel` itself.

In response to [gasmans answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65497556/wagtail-how-to-link-a-model-to-an-orderable-which-links-to-another-model/65499182#65499182) & additional information:

`"it would correspond to each club having multiple timetabled sessions"` yes this would be the desired behaviour.
A club could host a session in location_A: Tue, Thur at 8pm and location_B: Sat 9am, Sun 2pm for example.

Ideally it would need to offer entering all information in the same place as too few places can be reused for
it to warrant separate entry, assuming a larger organisation which could have dozens of clubs in England and several in Scotland, Wales, Ireland, then,
many events nationally and internationally - all of which require location. I figure having some duplicate location entires would therefore be acceptable as a trade-off (and more manageable?).

Following the abstract model idea, would it make sense to have a base `Address` then have `club_location` and `event_location` act as middlemen between their respective models and `Address`? Like so:

[image: Visual Aid of a possible workaround.]

With this, it would solve:

- The many location related fields would be in their own tables, rather than in the model using it
- The `Orderable` would work similar to how it is now
- `InlinePanel` would not be nested, and,
- I would only need to change `Address` fields/methods to have it change throughout.

It's an extra step (for the developer) but I imagine it to be more maintainable now and later for this use-case.

Please tell me if there could be hiccups doing it this way which I've not foreseen?

Answer (score 0):

Nesting an InlinePanel inside another InlinePanel isn't currently supported in Wagtail, although that wouldn't be the right pattern for this anyhow (it would correspond to each club having multiple timetabled sessions, and each session having multiple venues - and for that you'd need a ParentalKey from Address to ClubTimetable.)

The abstract model is probably the best approach if you want the address fields to be filled in against each session. Another possible option is to keep the Address model as it is now, and [register it as a snippet](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/topics/snippets.html) so that there's a standalone view where addresses can be added - you can then use a SnippetChooserPanel (or [wagtail-autocomplete](https://wagtail-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) in your ClubTimetable model to select from the existing addresses. While this does add an extra step for content editors when adding a new address, it has the advantage that the same Address record can be re-used for multiple sessions.

Comment: I had lots to think about, thank you for your thoughts on this. My reply was too long so I've appended it to my question if you could take a look there?